# Поиск по сайту с кнопкой "Ещё результаты"

Tags: поиск, wordpress

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, как можно реализовать кнопку "Ещё результаты" на движке Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Недавно натолкнулся на интересный [пост.](http://yacoder.ru/archives/314)
Возможно, кому-нибудь понадобится.